# Location in ocean furthest from any land. Are there any established organized travel options for a tourist?

Tags: travel-agents, extreme-tourism, pacific-ocean

As far as I know the point in the world's oceans furthest from any land is located in the Southern Pacific, roughly halfway on a direct line from the Marquesas Islands (French Polynesia) in the west and the Galapagos in the east.

It's a bit over 2500 km to these island groups and about the same to Easter Island (south), Socorro Island (north) and Pitcairn (south-west).
(If I'm wrong and there is a more remote spot in the oceans, feel free to edit the above. Question remains the same.)

Is there any possibility for a tourist to get there by some form of organized travel, that runs on a more or less regular basis? 
(Either by ship or a fly-by.)

This is to satisfy the curiosity of me and some friends. This started with "Name any place of interest in the world and there will be a travel agency organizing regular trips to it, so people can go there for bragging rights".
So far, we haven't been able to find a travel agency organizing travel to this particular spot.

To further clarify:
We are looking for a travel agency that offers this as (part of) a bookable, standard trip, and has made the trip at least once before. (Otherwise, with enough money, someone can always pay a travel agency to organize a one-off trip. That doesn't count.)
It is fine if these trips are are not on a regular schedule and are on demand only.
We are ok with any trip that includes this spot in the itinerary, but doesn't have it as the main goal. (I can imagine some cruise ship will pass it going from the Galapagos to French Polynesia.)

Comment: Not much help but there's a term for places like this: *Pole of inaccessibility* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_of_inaccessibility

Comment: not sure I accept your premise at all. Eg I am not aware of packages to take you to the non-polar place where the 180 meridian crosses land - there's only one such place, and there's a sign there, but no tours. Ditto "the southernmost place in continental Asia" (an island connected by a bridge to another island connected by a bridge etc to mainland Asia - there are other islands further south but they are not connected.) Then there are the various "height of land" spots on all the large continents. These just places I have been to - dozens more could easily be named.

Comment: @KateGregory You just extended our most "notable places"' list. We were mostly going by northernmost/southernmost etc point on each continent. Highest mountain, deepest valley, etc. Had 0-meridian on the list, but not the 180. How far south can you in Asia was still on our research list.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I didn't know there was a term for i. Thank you for the info.

Comment: No one is going to create a tour unless people want to go there.  I can't imagine there would be much demand to go to the place furthest from anything but water.

Comment: Do you need 7 nights there or 14?